# Unmarshal XML files with DOCTYPE ENTITY declarations using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm `unmarshalling` a few XML files present in my local file system using `JAXB`.

The `unmarshalling` goes alright as long as the source XML does not have any `ENTITY` declarations in it. But a few XML files among those import some XML files with a `DOCTYPE ENTITY` declaration using relative paths. This causes the `JAXB` to fail trying to locate the files that are imported since the relative paths have absolutely no connection to the current classpath and so `FileNotFoundException`s occur. How do I resolve this?

FWIW, I do have the model JAVA object equivalents of the complex types in the XML in my classpath (like the `Root` class used below) as a `jar` that was generated using the `maven-jaxb-plugin`.

The DOCTYPE declarations in the XML files:

```
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ENTITY decorator SYSTEM "relative/path/to/another/xmlfile">
]>
```

The code I use to unmarshal the XMLs:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
JAXBElement<Root> unmarshalledObject = (JAXBElement<Root>) unmarshaller
        .unmarshal(new FileInputStream(new File("/absolute/path/to/my/xmlfile")));
Root rootNode = unmarshalledObject.getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Access to a file or directory via a relative pathname has nothing to do with the class path.

A relative pathname is resolved using System property `user.dir`, the working directory at the time the Java application is started.

You might try and start the application from the parent directory of those relative paths.

According to the XML spec, a *relative* external identifier should be relative to the XML file where it is used, so that's another opportunity.